# Error compiling Cython file: Invalid types for `'>'` (`float64_t[::1]`, `float64_t`)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, cython

## Context

I am attempting to cythonise a function to replace a filtering operation on an extremely large `pandas.DataFrame` (100,000,000 rows). Currently it compares values in the `df` columns (`Z, T, M`) against single values (`Z1, Z2, T1, T2, M1, M2`), but will eventually be performed rowise for 1D arrays of those values:

```
# Python
# df: pandas.DataFrame
# Z, T, M: columns of df, float64 values
# I: column of df, uint32 values
# Z1, Z2, T1, T2, M1, M2: float64 values

res = df.query(
    f"{Z1} < Z < {Z2} and {T1} < T < {T2} and {M1} < M < {M2}",
    engine="numexpr",
)[["T", "I", "M"]]
```

`df.query(..., engine="numexpr")` is already an improvement in speed over `df.loc[(df['Z'] > Z1) & (df['Z'] < Z2) & ...]`. I have even improved it further using the decorator `@jit(nopython=False, cache=True, parallel=True)`.

## Error

I am now attempting to refactor this for use with **cython**. However, after many multiple rounds of bugfixing and refinement I cannot get it to build using the following command (executed in the terminal in the same directory as the `module.pyx`, `setup.py` and `pyproject.toml`):

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

I am now stuck with the following error which I can't resolve:

```
Error compiling Cython file: Invalid types for '>' (float64_t[::1], float64_t)
```

This is my first time cythonising code, I have read the following useful documentation:

- [Installing cython](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/install.html)
- [Source files and compilation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html)
- [Working with python arrays](https://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/array.html)
- [Basic tutorial](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html)
- [Typed memoryviews](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#memoryviews)
- [Cython for numpy users](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html#numpy-tutorial)
- [Pandas enhancing performance](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html)

## Files

### setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy
from Cython.Build import build_ext, cythonize
from setuptools import Extension, setup

extensions = [Extension("module", ["module.pyx"])]

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions),
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
    cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
)
```

### pyproject.toml

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel", "Cython"]
```

### module.pyx

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# cython: infer_types=True

import numpy as np
DTYPE = np.dtype(
    [('T', np.float64), ('I', np.uint32), ('M', np.float64)]
)

cimport cython
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef packed struct result_struct:
    np.float64_t T
    np.uint32_t I
    np.float64_t M

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef filter_function(
    np.ndarray[(
        np.uint32_t, 
        np.uint32_t, 
        np.uint32_t, 
        np.uint32_t, 
        np.float64_t, 
        np.float64_t, 
        np.float64_t, 
        np.float64_t
    ), ndim=2] df, 
    np.float64_t Z1, 
    np.float64_t Z2, 
    np.float64_t T1, 
    np.float64_t T2, 
    np.float64_t M1, 
    np.float64_t M2
):
    # Types
    cdef np.uint32_t[:, ::1] I = df[3]
    cdef np.float64_t[:, ::1] Z = df[4]
    cdef np.float64_t[:, ::1] M = df[5]
    cdef np.float64_t[:, ::1] T = df[7]

    cdef Py_ssize_t i, n

    # Output array
    n = df.shape[0]
    cdef np.ndarray[result_struct, ndim=2] result = np.zeros((n, 3), dtype=DTYPE)

    cdef np.float64_t[:, ::1] result_T = result['T']
    cdef np.uint32_t[:, ::1] result_I = result['I']
    cdef np.float64_t[:, ::1] result_M = result['M']

    # Filter
    for i in range(n):
        if (Z[i] > Z1) and (Z[i] < Z2) and (T[i] > T1) and (T[i] < T2) and (M[i] > M1) and (M[i] < M2):
            result_T[i] = T[i]
            result_I[i] = I[i].astype(np.uint32)
            result_M[i] = M[i]
    
    # Remove rows with 0
    result = result[(result != 0).all(axis=1)]

    return result
```

I appreciate any help offered.

If there is a better way to achieve the task of filtering on values/1D arrays of values, I welcome suggestions.

Also, I'd like to check that my use of memoryviews and contiguous data is correct. Would I need to create a subset of `df` with the columns `'I', 'Z', 'M', 'T'` so that `'T'` is contiguous, or if it is a memoryview of `df` does it not matter (`df.to_numpy()` is used before supplying as an argument to the `filter_function()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get the structured array approach to compile. However, I didn't spend a lot of time on that, as my understanding is that converting from a structured array to a DataFrame requires copying the array, as Pandas doesn't support NumPy's structured arrays. Instead, I treated each column as a separate array.

This code manipulates the DataFrame a little, so it does interact with Python a bit, but I kept that out of the loop. It ended up being about 3x faster than the naive Pandas approach.

I'm able to get this to work with the following changes:

module.pyx:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
cimport numpy as cnp
cimport cython
cnp.import_array()

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef filter_df_cy_no_pd(df, double Z1, double Z2, double T1, double T2, double M1, double M2):
    # Get NumPy array for each column
    cdef cnp.float64_t[::1] Z = df['Z'].values
    cdef cnp.float64_t[::1] T = df['T'].values
    cdef cnp.float64_t[::1] M = df['M'].values
    cdef cnp.int32_t[::1] I = df['I'].values

    cdef Py_ssize_t n = Z.shape[0]
    T_out_arr = np.empty(n + 1, dtype='float64')
    cdef cnp.float64_t[::1] T_out = T_out_arr
    I_out_arr = np.empty(n + 1, dtype='int32')
    cdef cnp.int32_t[::1] I_out = I_out_arr
    M_out_arr = np.empty(n + 1, dtype='float64')
    cdef cnp.float64_t[::1] M_out = M_out_arr

    cdef cython.bint in_range = 0
    cdef Py_ssize_t out_idx = 0
    cdef Py_ssize_t burn_idx = n
    for i in range(n):
        
        in_range = (
            (Z1 < Z[i]) and (Z[i] < Z2) and
            (T1 < T[i]) and (T[i] < T2) and
            (M1 < M[i]) and (M[i] < M2)
        )
        write_idx = out_idx if in_range else burn_idx
            
        T_out[write_idx] = T[i]
        I_out[write_idx] = I[i]
        M_out[write_idx] = M[i]

        out_idx += 1 if in_range else 0

    T_out_arr = T_out_arr[:out_idx]
    I_out_arr = I_out_arr[:out_idx]
    M_out_arr = M_out_arr[:out_idx]

    return pd.DataFrame({
        'T': T_out_arr,
        'I': I_out_arr,
        'M': M_out_arr,
    }, copy=False)
```

setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy
from Cython.Build import build_ext, cythonize
from setuptools import Extension, setup

extensions = [
    Extension(
        "module",
        ["module.pyx"],
        define_macros=[("NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API", "NPY_1_7_API_VERSION")],
        extra_compile_args=["-O3"],
    )
]
setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions, language_level=3),
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
    cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
)
```

Example test code:

```
import module
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
N = 1000000*100
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Z": (np.random.rand(N) * 10).astype('float64'),
    "T": (np.random.rand(N) * 10).astype('float64'),
    "M": (np.random.rand(N) * 10).astype('float64'),
    "I": (np.random.rand(N) * 10).astype('int32'),
})
t0 = time.time()
df_filt = module.filter_df_cy_no_pd(df, 1, 9, 1, 9, 1, 9)
t = time.time()
print(f"Duration: {t - t0:.3f}")
print(df_filt)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am able to compile it. However, there were 2 warnings: ignoring unknown compiler argument `-O3`; `warning C4005: '__pyx_nonatomic_int_type': macro redefinition`. I think the first is due to my build environment is Windows, so the compiler MSVC lacks `-O3` as an argument; I think the equivalent is `-O2` from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/o-options-optimize-code?view=msvc-170). Also, after editing, the compilation fails if the module is currently loaded. Is there a way around it other than restarting IPython kernel/VS Code?

Comment: I don't specifically need to have the `pandas` `df` as the arg, I could use `df['Z'].to_numpy()` for each column and supply them separately as args if it would be quicker. I also don't mind if the output is a `numpy.ndarray` if that makes it quicker.

If I am to supply arrays instead of individual values to replace `Z1, Z2, T1, T2, M1, M2`, how would this modify the `for` loop?

Comment: Sorry, the method I'm using ends up restarting Python every time I want to compile/load the module, so I've never run into that.

Comment: Yes, that seems correct. I think -O2 is the equivalent on Windows.

Comment: The issue is that you need to convert the DataFrame into a NumPy representation at some point. You can do it inside the function, or outside the function, but neither is faster. It makes the function faster, but only because you're pushing some of the work into the caller. I did it inside the function because it makes the API simpler.

Comment: I've been trying to extend this code so that I can perform it when `Z1, Z2, T1, T2, M1, M2` are each 1D arrays instead of single values: `for row in range(Z1.shape[0]):` but I'm not able to realise it and store the subset arrays of `M, T, I` for each set of 'row' values. I think it's because the subsets are all different lengths.