# cython binary search in parallel

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, cython, gil

## Context

Following cythonisation ([see original SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77077239/10771401)) of a function to replace a filtering operation on an extremely large `pandas.DataFrame` (100,000,000 rows), **I now need to vectorise the operation and do so utilising parallel processing**.

The original **python** version which compares values in the `df` columns (`Z, T, M`) against single values (`Z1, Z2, T1, T2, M1, M2`):

```
# Python
# df: pandas.DataFrame
# Z, T, M: columns of df, float64 values
# I: column of df, uint32 values
# Z1, Z2, T1, T2, M1, M2: float64 values

res = df.query(
    f"{Z1} < Z < {Z2} and {T1} < T < {T2} and {M1} < M < {M2}",
    engine="numexpr",
)[["T", "I", "M"]]
```

The **cython** [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77078861/10771401), with thanks to @Nick ODell:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
cimport numpy as cnp
cimport cython
cnp.import_array()

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef filter_df_cy_no_pd(df, double Z1, double Z2, double T1, double T2, double M1, double M2):
    # Get NumPy array for each column
    cdef cnp.float64_t[::1] Z = df['Z'].values
    cdef cnp.float64_t[::1] T = df['T'].values
    cdef cnp.float64_t[::1] M = df['M'].values
    cdef cnp.int32_t[::1] I = df['I'].values

    cdef cnp.float64_t[::1] T_out = np.empty_like(T)
    cdef cnp.int32_t[::1] I_out = np.empty_like(I)
    cdef cnp.float64_t[::1] M_out = np.empty_like(M)

    cdef Py_ssize_t n = Z.shape[0]
    cdef cython.bint in_range = 0
    cdef Py_ssize_t out_idx = 0
    for i in range(n):

        in_range = (
            (Z1 < Z[i]) & (Z[i] < Z2) &
            (T1 < T[i]) & (T[i] < T2) &
            (M1 < M[i]) & (M[i] < M2)
        )
        if in_range:
            T_out[out_idx] = T[i]
            I_out[out_idx] = I[i]
            M_out[out_idx] = M[i]
            out_idx += 1

    T_out_arr = np.asarray(T_out)[:out_idx]
    I_out_arr = np.asarray(I_out)[:out_idx]
    M_out_arr = np.asarray(M_out)[:out_idx]

    return pd.DataFrame({
        'T': T_out_arr,
        'I': I_out_arr,
        'M': M_out_arr,
    }, copy=False)
```

## Problem

My attempts to parallelise the function have been in vain, failing when compiling.

**Attempts**

- The `df` parameter has been replaced with:

```
cnp.uint32_t[::1] I
cnp.float64_t[::1] Z
cnp.float64_t[::1] T
cnp.float64_t[::1] M
```

- `Z1, Z2, T1, T2, M1, M2` parameters are now `cnp.float64_t[::1]`.
- These parameters are now `pandas.Series` created in python and supplied to the function call as `numpy.ndarray` with the `.to_numpy()` method.
- I modified the cython function definition from `cpdef` to `cdef` along with adding `noexcept nogil`.
- `for i in range(n)` changed to `for i in prange(n, nogil=True)`, along with including `from cython.parallel import prange` at the top of the `module.pyx`.
- The function `return` is `T_out_arr, I_out_arr, M_out_arr`
- I call this function from an outer `cpdef` function under the context manager:

```
cdef Py_ssize_t p, r
r = Z1.shape[0]
cdef object[:, :] output = np.empty((r, 3), dtype=object)
# `3` is due to the 3 arrays returned from the inner cdef `filter_cy()` function

with nogil:
    for p in range(r):
        output_nested[p, :] = filter_cy(
            # args...
        )
```

**Errors**

Some of the numerous errors include:

- `Function with Python return type cannot be declared nogil`
- `Calling gil-requiring function not allowed without gil`
- `Accessing Python attribute not allowed without gil`
- `Cannot read reduction variable in loop body`

I understand that the nature of most of the problems stem from the presence of python objects inside the inner `cdef` function, but I'm finding trying to implement other alternatives tricky. I don't know if it would be better to parallelise the outer loop within which the inner `cdef` function is called, but ideally I need to speed up the inner filtering operation as that is the bottleneck.

Moreover, I haven't begun to try to construct a binary search implementation in the inner function. The way I was thinking about it would be possibly to sort each `numpy.ndarray` in the python function call, then in the inner function get the indices of the matches, then intersect the indices, and then use those indices to get the values in the outer function? I don't know if that's the best approach (or how to actually engineer it).

I appreciate any help offered.

Comment: `np.empty` with object dtype containd references to python objects (initially `None`).  Can't bypass the `gil` with such an array. It is `list` like.

Comment: What makes Cython fast is using native types instead of objects. Cython cannot operate on object in parallel (efficiently) because of the GIL. It is the purpose of the GIL to serialize operations on objects so to protect the interpreter. Thus, object-based codes are inherently slow and there is no possible workaround (as mentioned by hpaulj) apart from using processes (which are also slow due to IPC/pickling). Thus, you need to remove all objects from your code if you want a fast code : only use native types. There is no free lunch.

Comment: I did not understand why parallelizing the first code results in having objects. It is not clear to me what you try to parallelize. The first code cannot be trivially parallelized due to `out_idx`. While they are ways to parallelize the computation, the solutions may not be significantly faster regarding your constraints (does the order matters?) and your target platform (memory bandwidth, number of cores, etc.).

Comment: @JérômeRichard, @hpaulj thank you for your comments. As I mentioned, I have understood the failure to compile is due to the presence of python objects. I removed all but 2 `CompileError`s using a single `cpdef` function that loops over each index of the typed `memoryviews` of the length of `Z1` etc., followed by a nested `for i in prange(n, nogil=True)` loop: `local variable 'out_idx' referenced before assignment`, `Cannot read reduction variable in loop body`. I can't figure out how to resolve those errors. I'd like to know how to overcome `out_idx`, or performing binary searches in cython.

Comment: IDK if this is related but I as pointed out before *"The first code cannot be trivially parallelized due to `out_idx`"* . Using `prange` in this case will at best compile and cause a race condition (i.e. random bug). Thread cannot read and write the same variable without a protection. And adding a protection will make the code slow. You need to think twice before parallelizing this since this is not so simple. Regarding the binary search, you can do that in Numpy using `searchsorted`.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yes, thank you. I found `threadid()`, although I don't yet know how to use it. I understand it currently doesn't lend itself to parallelisation, but I don't know how to implement an alternative. Would this be a possible/sensible approach, to remove `out_idx`, assign `T_out[i] = T[i]` etc., then keep indices (`i`) where values are present? If you look at the previous SO post I linked to, I did try something similar to `T_out_arr = T_out[T_out != 0]`, but ran into errors. Whether or not parallelisation results in faster execution will be for benchmarking, but I must at least try.

Comment: Keeping the indices just shifts the issue and does not solve it : how to store the indices (contiguously) using multiple threads efficiently? Doing a selection using `T_out[T_out != 0]` is not very efficient in practice (it might be fast enough for you though). In general, there are 3 approaches to solve this issue : 1) operating on chunks and then merge them, 2) compute chunks and add the result atomically, 3) use a scan implementation (only efficient on GPUs or CPUs with wide SIMD registers). If you care about the order, then this is a bit more complex (the 2 pass solution is the simplest).

Comment: This is why I ask before *"does the order matters?"* .

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yes, I discovered `searchsorted()` and implemented an approach in python that firstly `.sorts_values()`, then `.index.searchsorted()`, and `numpy.intersect1d()`, but I'm not quite getting the same results. In any case, the sort takes some time (although performed once), so I don't yet know if it would be better than a properly implemented version of the cython function.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, @hpaulj regarding removal of python objects, would `from cpython cimport array; import array; cdef array.array` be a replacement, or usage of `malloc`, `free`, `sizeof`? As is clear I have no knowledge of C programming & I'm new to cython, I would appreciate an example of how to implement it (it's my understanding that `cdef object[:, :] output = np.empty()` is the offence here).

Comment: @JérômeRichard each index of `I, Z, T, M` corresponds to values belonging to the same row of original `df` & similarly `Z1, Z2, T1, T2, M1, M2` values at each index belong together, so in this respect the order matters, but I guess as long as the same index is processed for a given iteration the order does not matter (although I would have to sort outputs by `T` for each `i`, probably in python). Would it be possible to provide an example of any of the parallelisation suggestions, even a simple toy example would help me to understand how to implement it, otherwise could you provide some links?

Comment: *EDIT: "I would have to sort outputs by `T` for each"* `p`